# Open File or Project, Gradle not loading project

Tags: android-studio

I recently downloaded the code examples that come with Android Studio Third Edition. Whenever I go to "Open File or Project" and select my app project: Gradle starts to build it but then stays building it forever. This never happens when I build a new project from scratch. I have no idea what is wrong. Could someone please try and point me in the right direction? Thanks!!

Comment: What happens if you go into the directory and enter `./gradlew build` (or just `gradlew build` if you are on Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**
 1. Open `app/build.gradle` file in text editor
 2. Change the `buildToolsVersion "XX.X.X"` to your current buildToolsVersion

*Now Gradle will build the project and project will be opened.*